# Not able to add key value pair in a json object from a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to add key value pair to my json object from another json object.

I tried to read many stackoverflow  similar questions but none of those solutions work in my case.

```js
const oValues = {
  action: "Open Browser & Login",
  password: "something",
  url: "https://***manage",
  user: "user1",
}

var mElementsData = {
  pages: [{
    groups: [{
      elements: [{}]
    }]
  }]
};

for (var key in oValues) {
  if (oValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    mElementsData.pages.groups.elements["label"] = key;
    mElementsData.pages.groups.elements["value"] = oValues[key];
  }
}

console.log(mElementsData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested properties are not objects, but arrays of objects, so you cannot access them by dot notation. You can access them by index, here is an example:

```js
const oValues = {
  action: "Open Browser & Login",
  password: "something",
  url: "https://***manage",
  user: "user1",
}

var mElementsData = {
  pages: [{
    groups: [{
      elements: []
    }]
  }]
};

for (var key in oValues) {
  if (oValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const element = {
      label: key,
      value: oValues[key]
    };
    mElementsData.pages[0].groups[0].elements.push(element);
  }
}

console.log(mElementsData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `pages`, `groups` and `elements` elements are all arrays of objects, so you need to reference the specific array element (`[0]`) to set the value:

```js
var mElementsData = {
  pages: [{
    groups: [{
      elements: [{}]
    }]
  }]
};

var oValues = {
  key: "value"
};

for (var key in oValues) {
  if (oValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    mElementsData.pages[0].groups[0].elements[0]["label"] = key;
    mElementsData.pages[0].groups[0].elements[0]["value"] = oValues[key];
  }
}
console.log(mElementsData);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pages** and **groups** are ***array*** so you have to loop over and bind the object with key and value pair

```
var mElementsData = {
   pages: [{
        groups: [{
            elements: [{}]
        }]
    }]
};

var oValues = {
    action: "Open Browser & Login",
    password: "something",
    url: "https://***manage",
    user: "user1",
}

for (var key in oValues) {
    if (oValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mElementsData.pages.length; i++) {
            let pages = mElementsData.pages[i]
            for (let j = 0; j < pages.groups.length; j++) {
                pages.groups[j].elements[j][key] = oValues[key]
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(mElementsData)
```